# Quickly find implemented interfaces of a C# class in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface

Javadocs provides excellent references for classes. I can see the implemented interface of a JAVA class in just a blink of an eye (with a summary of all implemented interface).

[image: Javadocs screenshot]

Things are different when I come to Visual studio. I can peek up the definition of a class but I find it is difficult to see interface information. Looking up at MSDN is too slow.

Is there any way that I can find such information quickly in VS?

Thanks.

Comment: For cases when you have the source-code, VS2015 added "Go to Implementation" - if more than 1 implementatione exists it shows all of them in the Find Symbols window, though this does not extend to types and methods referenced in existing assemblies.

Comment: the object browser gives all this?

Comment: How did you get that screenshot?